# Python pandas groupby key error in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am doing what seems to be a simple group by in Pandas. The column is a string column with no NaN's or weird strings. However, I keep getting the below error. Does anyone know why this mights happen? I feel like it may have something to do with my data, but it all seems to be ok...

I am running `by_user = df.groupby('User')`

and the stack trace:

```
by_user = df.groupby('User')
File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2773, in groupby
sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze)
File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1142, in groupby
return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 388, in __init__ level=level, sort=sort)
File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2041, in _get_grouper
gpr = obj[gpr]
File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1678, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1685, in _get      item_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1052, in _ge
t_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2565, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "c:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1181, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
File "index.pyx", line 129, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.
c:3656)
File "index.pyx", line 149, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.
c:3534)
File "hashtable.pyx", line 696, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
(pandas\hashtable.c:11911)
File "hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
(pandas\hashtable.c:11864)
KeyError: 'User'
```

`df.info():`

```
User Code        175167 non-null object
Version          175167 non-null object
Date Accessed    175167 non-null datetime64[ns]
Series           175167 non-null object
Software         175167 non-null object
User             175167 non-null object
```

Comment: Can you post the output from `df.info` also is `'User'` actually one of the columns?

Comment: @EdChum strangely (?) even if the column isn't found this shouldn't raise.

Comment: @EdChum I've added the `df.info`. `User` is in there, there are no nulls, it is a simple collection of names, and those names don't have any strange characters in them. This df is creating by `concat` on a bunch of *.xlsx files.

Comment: Just to check one more time -- because this is exactly what would happen if there were an extra space at the end of `User` -- could you edit to post the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: Just for completion please post your numpy, pandas and python version, thanks

Comment: @DSM: That's what it was... when I ran `df.columns` I got `User ` instead of `User`. If you want to make that the answer I'll select it. From now spaces in columns will go into my error checking. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[moved from comments]

It's easy to miss trailing whitespace in column names, but you can check `df.columns` manually:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"User": [1,2]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"User ": [1,2]})
>>> df
   User
0     1
1     2
>>> df2
   User 
0      1
1      2
>>> df.columns
Index([u'User'], dtype='object')
>>> df2.columns
Index([u'User '], dtype='object')
```

(To peel back the curtain a bit, I suspected something like this might be going on because when I mocked up my own DataFrame and looked at `df.info()`, I didn't see as much space between the column names and the numbers as your output seemed to show.)