# Jupyter Notebook Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am currently doing a data analysis course in Coursera and I am having issues with their autograder to deliver my exercises. The code seems to be well written as I get the right solution in the exercise however when the autograder checks the jupyter notebook it seems it get an exception message that I am posting below.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
(pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
(pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 'STNAME'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-12-0bb5f5883245> in <module>()
----> 1 answer_six()

<ipython-input-9-63797fbac390> in answer_six()
     23 
     24        #group table by stname and census, sorting only the 3 
 biggest counties population
---> 25     ccensus_groupby_state= (ccensus_df.groupby('STNAME') 
['CENSUS2010POP'].nlargest(3) )
     26     #print (ccensus_groupby_state)
     27     ft=(ccensus_groupby_state.reset_index())

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, 
**kwargs)
   3989         return groupby(self, by=by, axis=axis, level=level, 
as_index=as_index,
   3990                        sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, 
squeeze=squeeze,
-> 3991                        **kwargs)
   3992 
   3993     def asfreq(self, freq, method=None, how=None, 
 normalize=False):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in 
groupby(obj, by, **kwds)
   1509         raise TypeError('invalid type: %s' % type(obj))
   1510 
-> 1511     return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
   1512 
   1513

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in 
__init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, 
selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, **kwargs)
    368                                                     
level=level,
    369                                                     
sort=sort,
--> 370                                                     
mutated=self.mutated)
    371 
    372         self.obj = obj

 /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in 
_get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, mutated)
   2460 
   2461         elif is_in_axis(gpr):  # df.groupby('name')
-> 2462             in_axis, name, gpr = True, gpr, obj[gpr]
   2463             exclusions.append(name)
   2464         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not 
None:
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
__getitem__(self, key)
   2057             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2058         else:
-> 2059             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2060 
   2061     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
_getitem_column(self, key)
   2064         # get column
   2065         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2066             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2067 
   2068         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
_get_item_cache(self, item)
   1384         res = cache.get(item)
   1385         if res is None:
-> 1386             values = self._data.get(item)
   1387             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1388             cache[item] = res

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in 
get(self, item, fastpath)
   3541 
   3542             if not isnull(item):
-> 3543                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3544             else:
   3545                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items)) 
[isnull(self.items)]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:
-> 2136                 return 
self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2137 
   2138         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, 
tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
(pandas/index.c:4433)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
(pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
(pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 'STNAME'
```

Can someone help with this exception message? how do I fix this error so my exercise can be graded? I do understand that I may be accessing a key that does not exist but it is not the case as the algorithm is providing the right solution. It seems the problem is in the autograder and they way that Jupyter notebooks works.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to access a column that doesn't exist

Comment: Possibly related: [Python pandas groupby key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870428/python-pandas-groupby-key-error-in-pandas-hashtable-pyobjecthashtable-get-item)

Comment: Indeed! thanks very much for your help.